# how to specify C# / WPF resource files in cmake

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, cmake, visual-studio-2017

I need to specify resource files for **c-sharp / WPF via cmake**, these are image files that need to ship with the application GUI.

In Visual Studio you just: 
select the image -> Advanced -> Build Action -> select "Resource", this makes it possible to access the images directly in xaml, ex:

```
<Image Source="png/login.png"/>
```

For reference when done **manually in VS2017** this adds the following lines to the project.csproj:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="png/login.png">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Resource>
  </ItemGroup>
```

**So how do I specify resource files in cmake?**

I tried the suggestion here, to no avail:
https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17368

My current CMakeLists.txt looks as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2 FATAL_ERROR)

project(sampleApp VERSION 2.2.0 LANGUAGES CSharp)

include(CSharpUtilities)

add_executable(sampleApp app.config                     
                App.xaml
                App.xaml.cs                 
                MainWindow.xaml
                MainWindow.xaml.cs
                Styles.xaml
                Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs
                Properties/Resources.Designer.cs
                Properties/Resources.resx
                Properties/Settings.Designer.cs
                Properties/Settings.settings                
                 )

target_link_libraries(sampleApp PRIVATE otherLibrary)
#
# Tried this setting (does not work)
set(RESOURCES "png/login.png")
set_property(SOURCE ${RESOURCES} PROPERTY VS_TOOL_OVERRIDE "Resource")

csharp_set_designer_cs_properties(
    Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs
    Properties/Resources.Designer.cs
    Properties/Resources.resx
    Properties/Settings.Designer.cs
    Properties/Settings.settings)

csharp_set_xaml_cs_properties(
                App.xaml
                App.xaml.cs
                MainWindow.xaml
                MainWindow.xaml.cs 
                Styles.xaml)


target_compile_options(sampleApp PRIVATE "/langversion:6")
target_compile_options(sampleApp PRIVATE "/unsafe")

set_property(SOURCE App.xaml PROPERTY VS_XAML_TYPE "ApplicationDefinition")
set_property(TARGET sampleApp PROPERTY VS_DOTNET_TARGET_FRAMEWORK_VERSION "v4.6.1")
set_target_properties(sampleApp PROPERTIES WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE)

set_property(TARGET sampleApp PROPERTY VS_DOTNET_REFERENCES
"System"
"System.Configuration" 
"System.Configuration.Install" 
"System.Data" 
"System.Drawing" 
"System.Management" 
"System.Security" 
"System.Transactions" 
"System.Web" 
"System.Xml" 
"System.Core" 
"System.Xaml"
"System.Xml.Linq" 
"System.Data.DataSetExtensions" 
"PresentationCore" 
"PresentationFramework" 
"Microsoft.CSharp" 
"Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel"
"WindowsBase" 
)

#
# Install
#
install(TARGETS sampleApp EXPORT sampleAppTargets
  RUNTIME DESTINATION sampleApp/
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION sampleApp/
  LIBRARY DESTINATION sampleApp/
)
install(
  FILES
    ${RESOURCES}
  DESTINATION
    sampleApp/
  COMPONENT
    Devel
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with my project. To fix the issue, I had to explicitly add the image resource file in `add_executable` using CMake. So try something like this:

```
set(IMAGE_RESOURCE "png/login.png")

# Include the resource here with the other source files.
add_executable(sampleApp app.config                     
    App.xaml
    App.xaml.cs                 
    MainWindow.xaml
    MainWindow.xaml.cs
    Styles.xaml
    Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs
    Properties/Resources.Designer.cs
    Properties/Resources.resx
    Properties/Settings.Designer.cs
    Properties/Settings.settings
    ${IMAGE_RESOURCE}                
)

# Then set the file property.
set_property(SOURCE ${IMAGE_RESOURCE} PROPERTY VS_TOOL_OVERRIDE "Resource")
```

This let CMake pull in the image file into my Visual Studio project. Then, upon examining the PNG file properties in Visual Studio, the "Build Action" was set to "Resource".

Answer (score 1):

Overriding the build action using `SET_PROPERTY` did not quite do the job for me. The build action remained *Image*. However, the [ticket](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17368) you've linked uses `SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES`, which fixed the issue for me:

```
SET(IMAGE_RESOURCES
    "Icons/Foo.png"
    "Icons/Bar.png"
)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(MyApp
    App.config
    Application.cs

    ${IMAGE_RESOURCES}
)

SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(${IMAGE_RESOURCES} PROPERTIES VS_TOOL_OVERRIDE "Resource")
```

Answer (score 1):

I also couldn't get resources to embed themselves in the assembly. I just found what was missing.

Your CMakeLists.txt file needs

`set_property(TARGET yourTargetName PROPERTY VS_GLOBAL_RootNamespace yourRootNamespace)`

Substitute your own values for `yourTargetName` and `yourRootNamespace`, obviously.