# How to use icon files in WPF project built with CMake

Tags: c#, wpf, cmake, resources, icons

I am building a WPF project in C# with CMake.

However, I cannot figure out how to include an icon file in my application.
I have declared it as a source for the CMake target like this:

```
target_sources(IconResourceDemo
  PRIVATE
  [...]
  "MainWindow.xaml"
  "MainWindow.xaml.cs"

  "Image_16x.png"
)

set_property(SOURCE "Image_16x.png" PROPERTY VS_TOOL_OVERRIDE "Resource")
```

In the `MainWindow.xaml`, I try to use it like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <BitmapImage x:Key="exampleImage" UriSource="pack://application:,,,/IconResourceDemo;component/Image_16x.png" />
</Window.Resources>
```

This approach worked fine with a "native" Visual Studio project, where one adds an image and can then access it like in the `.xaml` file above. With CMake, the icon is not shown. Instead, I receive an `IOException` telling me that the resource `image_16x.png` cannot be found.

I have found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54672541/how-to-specify-c-sharp-wpf-resource-files-in-cmake) where it has been suggested to set a property/source file property an the image, but that made no difference for me.
Still, I think that some resource-related declaration is missing.

I have set up [a small and buildable example](https://github.com/Phoenox/IconResourceDemo) so you can check the full code.

Comment: I do not see in your example where you apply solution from first link

Comment: The [Resource File Pack URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#resource-file-pack-uris) seems to be wrong. If IconResourceDemo is the assembly name, the URI should be `/IconResourceDemo;component/Image_16x.png` or fully specified `pack://application:,,,/IconResourceDemo;component/Image_16x.png`.

Comment: @Clemens it is optional ... so `pack://application:,,,/` can be replaced with simple `/` ... from what i understand in dup is that he need to override tool to "Resource" for image for image file

Comment: @Selvin Sure, the prefix is added by the XAML parser. But not the `;component/` part. And the Build Action must of course be Resource.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I've added the full path specification in the XAML and the Build Action in CMake. The icon is still not showing.
However, thanks to the full path specification, I now get the explicit `IOException` telling me that the resource "image_16x.png" could not be found.